# Image Comparison(only specific region) in c#

Tags: c#

I need help in comparing two images for a specific region only. For example, i just want to compare the address part(highlighted) in 2 images

[image]

and if it matches, make the result as pass. Can anyone help? Attached is the screenshot.

In Image 1 Address rectangle is padded right and in image 2 Address rectangle is in padded left.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem and add your code

Comment: Your images do not match. The text on the left is bolder than the one on the right.

Comment: Yes, we need to show them in the output difference image. Here the problem is the position of rectangles are different in those 2 images. Can we compare only those rectangle part?